# Multitenancy in ElasticSearch 6.2

Tags: elasticsearch, multi-tenant

I have just started evaluating Elastic Search for a project. My Application is a multitenant application and the first thought that came to my mind was to have a different index for each document type and tenant. In this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-multi-tenancy) the elastic co. seems to be advising against too many indexes but this was in a time when they supported heterogeneous types in an index.

Since now they recommend a separate index for each document-type, is it safe to assume that the memory-problem that used to occur due to too many indexes is a non-issue?

Comment: it depends how many is "many" and on what kind of hardware you run your cluster that has to handle those "many" indexes... Please be more specific.

Comment: The Application is SAAS based. The document-type for each customer can range anywhere from 200 to 500. A group of customers will have dedicated elastic cluster for them. The group size depends on the data size and traffic from the customer. Hardware can range from 16GB RAM to 96 GB RAM.

Comment: Also, our application like salesforce is very configurable so for same module type the two customers can gave very different set of fields. So sharing an index between customers is absolutely no go. As per the ES 6.2 guidance the index should be created based on the type of document that it will contain (homogeneous). Are there any other considerations for creating indexes in a Multi-tenant setup?

Comment: I think I'm eligible to answer the question. I've implemented the same. You can create multiple indexes for the multiple tenants. This will help you data segregation. So inside an index, you can keep multiple types based on the customer requirement. and you're data will not be shared among any.

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned earlier, Elastic Search doesn't support types within an index check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html . Anyways we have figured out how to get around with this.

Comment: @Aashish Sooo, how did you figured it out?

Comment: @Anfelipe we changed our index model slightly. We are maintaining 1 index per tenant. All document types for the tenant will be added to the same index. Each doctype will have a unique typeId. To avoid index field mapping explosion we maintained a mapping table in our primary database Sql Server. As a result of this mapping table we have same field name in different document types

Comment: @Aashish : I'm just curious to know how many customers do you guys currently have? and did you guys run into any issues?

Comment: We are still in development phase, this was one of the design choices we incorporated as we are sure that we will hit Index Mapping Explosion

Answer (score -2):

The easiest approach will be have a layer of nesting.
Exampale:

```
"tenant-1":{ 
  "id": 1
 },
"tenant-2":{ 
  "id": "id-1"
 }
```